# Unable to deserialize the response - SetUserDataAsync

Tags: botframework

I upgraded my solution to v3.0 and trying to set auth token in BotUserData , but I am getting exception 'Unable to deserialize the response'.

```
 BotData userData = new BotData();
            userData.SetProperty<string>("token", authresult);
            await stateClient.BotState.SetUserDataAsync("emulator", "", userData);
```

any idea what is going wrong?

Comment: How do you create `stateClient`? Also, I believe the second parameter of `SetUserDataAsync` should not be left empty (this should be the user id, i.e. the key in the bot state store).

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the userId field to identify which user you are saving the data for (rather than use an empty string).

```
SetUserDataAsync(string channelId, string userId, BotData botData)
```

Comment: I am passing the userid, but still I am getting the error, Also I am trying to set the values in LoginController and not in MessageController

Comment: I am also facing same issue, in my scenario I was created the stateclient object like this var stateClient = new StateClient(new Uri("apis.skype.com/"));